# Drag route anywhere using Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to write an application that gives me the exact route of a subway.

When you use Google Maps it just connects two stops linearly, but not the actual way.

Is there a way to move a route anywhere on a map without being bound to roads?
If there's any solution (doesn't have to be with the Google Maps API) please let me know.

Edit:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6Anj.jpg)

[image]

Google shows the train route like the brown line, but the train actually drives the blue line. What I would like to do is get the blue line so that I can get the coordinates of the route and calculate the curves and elevation.
I know that I could add like 50 waypoint and get get a "fake" route with them, but I would like to have it automatic and not done by hand.

Comment: You can provide latitude and longitude for every point you desire and connect them.
Please can you explain more precisely what are you trying to do, posting two images (current and desired output)? I will be glad to help you.

Comment: I'm just at the planning, that's why I don't have any code yet.

I edited the post. Maybe that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

To show the transit directions (subway, bus, tram, etc.) Google Maps uses the data provided by transit agencies in the form of GTFS feeds. This is a responsibility of the agency to provide a detailed shape of the route for the transport according to the GTFS specification. You can have a look at GTFS documentation to figure out how does it work:

https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/

https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference/#general_transit_feed_specification_reference

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'll take it into consideration! Thank you!!